# automate usage of SSH local key for git deployment with ansible

Tags: git, deployment, vagrant, ssh-keys, ansible

I am working with vagrant and ansible. I want to automate the **deployment** role of ansible ([You can check my repo here](https://github.com/oskargicast/django-provision)).
For this purpose, I am trying to deploy my local ssh key into my VPS and my vagrant guest machine (I am trying SSH agent forwarding).

**GOAL**

Automate deployment process with git using ansible. I've already done this:

```
---

- name: read-write git checkout from github
  git: repo={{ repository }} dest=/home/site
```

Where:

```
---
# Variables here are applicable to all host groups

repository: git@bitbucket.org:dgnest/dgnest.git
```

**PROBLEM**

When I do: "vagrant provision", the console stop here:

```
TASK: [deployment | read-write git checkout from github] **********************
```

That's because I haven't set up the ssh keys.

**I TRIED**

I would like to use the *key_file* option that the git module of ansible has. But it fails too.

```
---                                                                             

- name: read-write git checkout from github                                     
  git: repo={{ repository }} dest=/home/site key_file=/home/oscar/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Another option is to copy my **~/ssh/id_rsa.pub** into each VPS and vagrant, but my problem in this case is to handle with all the different users. Vagrant uses the "vagrant" user and my VPS uses another ones, so I had to put my ssh local key into each of these user?

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I've just automated the @leucos answer (Thanks). Copying the private and public rsa keys. I share **[this link](https://github.com/oskargicast/django-provision/blob/master/provisioning/roles/webapp/tasks/main.yml)** with the implementation.

Comment: Copying private RSA keys is really bad idea. Sharing private keys is really bad idea. For example, do you trust your team-mates (and all other staff who has access to the remote server) that you share with them access to your private repositories? If no — keep your private key _private_.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you choose the `key_file` way, my guess is that the key must be on the VPS/vagrant machine. So you might want to copy it first. Note that you need a private key here, not a public one.

For your second option, you could push your key to specific users depending on the instance type. Suppose the user in VPS is vpsuser, and that you deploy mostly on these VPS, you could do :

**group_vars/all :**

```
deploy_user=vpsuser
```

**group_vars/vagrant**

```
deploy_user=vagrant
```

Then, you could have a playbook like :

```
- name: send key to remote deploy user
  copy: src=files/private_key dest=~/{{deploy_user}}/.ssh/priv_key

- name: read-write git checkout from github                                     
  git: repo={{ repository }} dest=/home/site key_file=~/{{deploy_user}}/.ssh/priv_key
```

However, I have no idea how the password for the remote private key might be asked (I don't think ansible allows authentication agent forwarding by default (check `-vvvv` output), you might have to fiddle with your `~/.ansible.cfg`).

I suggest that you use a specific key for deployment purposes (with read-only perms on your git repository). This way, your private key won't leave your machine. Make this special key password-less. I think the security trade-off is acceptable since 
- it will just protect your code, 
- your code is checked out on the machine where the private key is so the game is already over.

Another option is to distribute your application from your local checkout using ansible : make a tarball, copy files over, untar, and you're set. This way, you don't need to leave security credentials on your VPS.

Good luck.

Answer (score 35):

You **don't** have to copy your local SSH key to remote servers. Instead, you just create file named `ansible.cfg` in the directory you are running deployment scripts from, and put the next settings:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

That's it, now your local identity is forwarded to the remote servers you manage with Ansible.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But in my practice you need setup server on root and deploy with other user. SSH forvarding work only with user, wich connected on ssh. If you want to use it with other no-root user, you should split you ansible playbook, One you connect by root and install all, other you do deploy buy other user. In this configuration you can deploy from private repo with normal user without any ssh key. Work like a charm with Django + Ansible.

Comment: SSH agent forwarding is insecure and if your remote server is compromised, an attacker could potentially use it to access servers the agent's keys enable him to. From `man ssh` on the `-A` option: "Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution. Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded connection. An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent."